# How to split an integer in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want to split the given integer in groovy. Say for example,

```
 def a = 198
    println(a.split())
```

However i get an error, because i could not apply the `split` method to an integer, so is there any way or method to do this. What i want is this:

```
   def a = 198
   // what to do here?
   // i want to get an output like 1,9,8
   // any ideas?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only split Strings, though what you probably want is to simply do:

```
"$a".collect { it as Integer }
```

(which works as `String` is seen as a Collection of characters)

An alternative is:

```
"$a"*.toInteger()
```

Comment: But how does this code work? Because when i call split method, i got an error, but not in this case. Is this because of **$** operator?

Comment: when you do `def a = 189`, as is an `Integer`.  `"$a"` puts the variable `a` into a String.  split is a method that works on Strings

Comment: Actually, if you want to make each digit an entry in the list, the second line should be `"$a".toList().collect { it as Integer }`

Comment: @Matt or just `"$a".collect { it as Integer }` as String behaves like a list of chars

Comment: @tim_yates excellent point!  If you edit your answer to reflect that, I'll vote it up. :)

Comment: @tim_yates since the stringified number has no whitespace in it, the call to split() has no effect, so I think you should just edit that part of your answer out.  Sorry I wasn't clearer in my previous comment.

Comment: @matt you're right, sorry about that (my only excuse is it's hard to test code on my phone -- but that's no excuse) ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates I was going to suggest the [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/), but I can't get it to work on my phone. ;)

Comment: @matt Yeah...i keep meaning to fork it on github to see if I can fix that ;)